# Where is "Applications > System Tools > File Types Editor" in 10.10?

Tags: 10.10, file-format

I was following this [link](http://ubuntugenius.wordpress.com/2009/12/09/how-to-open-url-internet-explorer-shortcuts-in-ubuntu-using-firefox/) to set up for opening Internet Explorer .url files. But I cannot find "Applications > System Tools > File Types Editor" in 10.10. So I wonder how to do this equivalently in 10.10?

Or do you have some better way to set up for opening .url files?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Ubuntu 9.10 is no longer maintained. You should consider upgrading to 11.10 or 10.04 LTS, which is supported for another year and 5 months on the desktop.

Comment: I am sorry. My bad.  Mine is not 9.10 but 10.10.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the File Types Editor in currently supported releases of Ubuntu by installing the package called "assogiate". (You can use the Ubuntu Software Center for this.)

Alternatively, you can right-click on a .url file and use Open With... to select the application you want, and check the box indicating that you want .url files to always be opened with that application.